# Virtualize an old MS-DOS machine to VMWare

Tags: virtual-machine, ms-dos, hardware-virtualization, vcenter

There is a very old workstation at a power plant running an MS-DOS system based HMI, I need to recover this and I believe the best way is to create a virtual machine from the old physical machine.

Anyone knows if this is supported by VMWare vCenter Converter 5.5 or an older version?

I'm planning to use Acronis to generate an image of the computer and then vCenter to convert that image to a virtual machine.

Please, any hint or recommendation??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

VMware does support DOS and Win3.1. [Instructions to install can be found here](http://partnerweb.vmware.com/GOSIG/MSDOS_6_22_and_Windows_3_1x.html).

vCenter convert 4.01 and above can convert TIB files with Acronis True Image Home 2010 and above if I recall correctly.

*(I have never tried this myself, just going off what should work.)*

Comment: I also want to note that Acronis TIH 2010 is newer than TIH 10.

Comment: I have done the conversion before from 2K and XP machines, using Acronis 11. Now, the link explains how to do a new installation of MS-DOS on a virtual machine, but my question is if the vCenter Converter is capable of convert an image of a DOS system to a VM by itself. Or do I have to install some extra stuff first?

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded to convert acronis image of DOS HMI to vmware but had to remove selection of "accelerate 3D graphics" in "Display" of "Virtual Machine Setting" when trying to run it.
Symptom: guest system freezed after displaying MS-DOS starting...
Had some error displayed by the costumer application for serial communication (missing native com2 port?) but com1 was working OK.

Had also to reduce ram memory size to 32 MB for an other HMI running under FlexOS of Siemens.
Symptom: wm reported system has crashed when loading FlexOS...
Did not test com port communication on this one.

You have to test functionnalities as some may not work...

Acronis True Image 10 Home
VMware vCenter Converter Standalone client 5.0.0
VMware Player 3.1.4
IBM laptop T30 and X60

Good luck!